# "Double" iterator and a generator function

Tags: python, iterator, generator

I want to get "next asset" with an iterator-like object, but (instead of `__next__()` method) there are two algorithms loading next asset (`next1` and `next2` below), which can be implemented as a "quasi-iterator" like:

```
class AssetLoader(object):
    def __init___(self):
        pass

    def next1(self):
        # ...

    def next2(self):
        # ...
```

To be clear, what is the next retrieved object may depends on the "history" of calling `next1` and `next2`, like:

`next1()`; `next1()`; `next2()`; `next1()`; `next2()`

My question: May this (two kinds of "next" step in an iterator) be implemented as a generator function?

I guess this can be done with a global variable to which the function refers. But can it be done without using global variables, but with some local variable?

If it is hard or impossible with current Python, can we discuss how to add new semantics to Python to make it possible?

Comment: Can you give a little more of context as to the logic behind the choosing of next1 or next2 to get the next element? Why a simple condition in \_\_next\_\_ would not be sufficient?

Comment: This sounds interesting... OTOH, it might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). ;) If you can give us a simple "fake" example of how you'd use this with the output it would produce it would make it a lot easier for us to understand what you want to do.

Comment: Is this like a binary tree?

Comment: @Chris_Rands No, they are not independent. I already said that the result depends on the sequence of `next1`/`next2`. It is not a binary tree

Comment: @Anis The real example would be too verbose to describe, sorry

Comment: @porton If you can't add more context, you won't get any useful answers.

Comment: We aren't asking for your real example. Just a _simple_ example that exhibits the kind of behaviour that you want to achieve. And then we can either a) show you code that does that, or b) tell you why it's not possible to do that using normal Python syntax. Python is very powerful & versatile, so my hopes are high for a). But without a clear problem statement I'm afraid your question won't be answerable.

Comment: I have a vague idea what you're trying to do, but I'm not going to write code that turns out to not do what you want. But anyway, there are ways to send data to a generator. And it's possible to save state in a generator that doesn't rely on globals. One of my favourite ways is to use a function attribute.

Comment: @PM2Ring Suppose we traverse (e.g BFS or DFS) a graph with red and blue edges. At next step we want to get the next node either through a red or through a blue edge, dependently on a variable value which may be red or blue

Comment: Ok. Does the code that calls the generator make the choice of red or blue? If so, that sounds like a job for [`send`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator.send).

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes, namely the code that calls the generator make the choice of red or blue

Comment: @PM2Ring Good job for figuring this question out!

Comment: Thanks, @SvenMarnach We should have a "Sherlock Holmes" badge for stuff like this. :)

Comment: @PM2Ring I would suggest a "Psychic" badge. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple example of using `send` to switch a generator between two different iteration modes: it either increments its current value or multiplies it. The same principle can be applied to your graph traversal task.

The `send` method allows you to send an object into the generator. Annoyingly, the result of `send` is the current value that you would have obtained by calling `next`; it would be nice if you could send without having the generator yield a value, but that's just something we have to live with.

```
def add_or_mul(current, step, scale, mode='add'):
    ''' A generator that either adds step to the current value,
        or multiplies it by scale
    '''
    while True:
        newmode = yield current
        if newmode is not None:
            if newmode not in ('add', 'mul'):
                raise ValueError('Bad mode: ' + newmode)
            mode = newmode
        if mode == 'add':
            current += step
        else:
            current *= scale

# Test

    gen = add_or_mul(1, 1, 2)
    for i in range(5):
        print(next(gen))
    print(gen.send('mul'))
    for i in range(4):
        print(next(gen))
    print(gen.send('add'))
    for i in range(4):
        print(next(gen))
```

**output**

```
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    10
    20
    40
    80
    160
    161
    162
    163
    164
    165
```

---

If you have trouble applying this technique to your graph traversal task please ask a fresh question (possibly linking to this one) that includes some relevant graph code, so that answerers don't have to write that stuff from scratch in order to test and demonstrate their code.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
class AssetLoader(object):
    def __init___(self):
        self.current_next = self.next1

    def next1(self):
        if condition:
            self.current_next = self.next2
        elif conition:
            return x
        else:
            raise StopIteration

    def next2(self):
        if condition:
            self.current_next = self.next1
        elif conition:
            return y
        else:
            raise StopIteration

    def __next__(self):
        return self.current_next()

    def __iter__(self):
        return self
```

Comment: `elif conition` sounds odd.

Comment: It is not an answer to my question: I have asked whether it is possible to implement as a generator function

Comment: @porton Your question is rather unclear.  Why do you need a generator function rather than a different kind of iterator?  And for what it's worth, it's quite simple to turn this implementation into a generator function.  Please show your attempts, then we may be able to understand your actual problem.

Comment: If the first `condition` in `next[12]` is met, the iterator will yield a `None` element, which seems wrong.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I want to try both a generator function and a regular object, to be sure I choose the best variant. The question is how to pass to the generator function whether we do `next1` or `next2` step. I could pass a global variable, but I am afraid it will be instead considered as a closure and change of the variable won't be reflected before the next step

Comment: @porton I don't understand your problem at all.  Why not simply store the current state in a local variable?

Comment: @SvenMarnach I want to consider to do this namely with a generator function. I just want to consider both iterator-like object and generator function to be sure I choose the best implementation of all possible ones

Comment: I don't get this answer at all. Why are there two `next1` and `next2` functions that sometimes set an attribute, othertimes return something, and sometimes throw an exception? What's the point of those? What do they do? How would I use this `AssetLoader` class?

Comment: don't blame the answer. The question is unclear for starters

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre That's precisely why I'm blaming the answer. An unclear answer on an unclear question isn't useful and shouldn't be posted.